# How to get 0/1 as binary prediction output instead of probabilities?

Tags: pandas, keras, neural-network, classification

I trained a neural network model and get the prediction results which are prob between `0` and `1`, how can I convert them into 0/1 instead of decimals? I managed to change them into bolean values:

```
y_pred

output:
array([[0.05447599],
       [0.09883076],
       [0.11023161],
       ...,
       [0.19569233],
       [0.07266018],
       [0.08473385]], dtype=float32)

y_pred_nn = (y_pred_nn > 0.5)

output:
array([[False],
       [False],
       [False],
       ...,
       [False],
       [False],
       [False]])
```

Expected result:

```
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       ...,
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
# just convert to floats then
y_pred_nn = (y_pred_nn > 0.5).astype(np.float32)
```